# "Missing source managed object model" error when making changes to data model

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, core-data-migration

I'm trying to add a new attribute to my entities but when I do it, the app crashes at launch on my phone, and it throws the following error:

Persistent store migration failed, missing source managed object model

When I remove the new attribute from every entity, the app launches normally.

I have no idea what may be causing this.
[image]

Comment: Look into CoreData model migration. Changes to the model (when it already contains data) forces CoreData to attempt a migration from the old to the new model but if it can’t do this itself it crashes. If the old data is important then you also need to produce a migration plan for CoreData to follow during the migration. During development it might be easier to simply delete your app from the simulator/phone and let CoreData start fresh with the new model.

Comment: @Magnas just found my way through the migration plan, I had to buy a Udemy course all focused on Core Data, but I actually could fix it with the lightweight migration, I just had no idea of how to do it, I thought it was done automatically 